# Parser version (undefined) doesn't match runtime version (13)

Tags: typescript, codemirror-6

I am trying to use the `lang-tex`  https://www.npmjs.com/package/lang-tex package in my react typescript project, after install the dependencies `"lang-tex": "^0.0.3"`, facing error:

```
Parser version (undefined) doesn't match runtime version (13)
RangeError: Parser version (undefined) doesn't match runtime version (13)
    at new _Parser (http://dev-tex.example.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-VML3AIQZ.js?v=f21e948c:11927:17)
    at _Parser.deserialize (http://dev-tex.example.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-VML3AIQZ.js?v=f21e948c:12198:16)
    at node_modules/.pnpm/lezer-tex@0.0.0-6_lezer@0.13.5/node_modules/lezer-tex/lib/index.js (http://dev-tex.example.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-VML3AIQZ.js?v=f21e948c:12402:37)
    at __require2 (http://dev-tex.example.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js?v=f21e948c:18:50)
    at node_modules/.pnpm/lang-tex@0.0.3_lezer@0.13.5/node_modules/lang-tex/lib/tex.js (http://dev-tex.example.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-VML3AIQZ.js?v=f21e948c:12908:23)
    at __require2 (http://dev-tex.example.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js?v=f21e948c:18:50)
    at node_modules/.pnpm/lang-tex@0.0.3_lezer@0.13.5/node_modules/lang-tex/lib/index.js (http://dev-tex.example.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-VML3AIQZ.js?v=f21e948c:17681:18)
    at __require2 (http://dev-tex.example.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js?v=f21e948c:18:50)
    at http://dev-tex.example.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/lang-tex.js?v=b8d748a1:6:16
```

I have tried to add the `"lezer": "^0.13.4"` and `"lezer-tex": "0.0.0-9"` dependencies in the project, still could not fixed this issue. where should I define the Parser? seems the project did not found the parser.